# Qbasic .exe to.bas

Tags: reverse-engineering, decompiling, basic, qbasic

I've just recently come across a really old QBasic app written in 1998. I'm interested in regaining the source code, as the app contains some valuable equations I'm in need of. I'm aware it may not be possible to regain the original source code, but how close could I get in "decompiling" the executable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIRC Qbasic was not a compiler but an interpreter? So the source code should be around somewhere if you can execute it.

Comment: I can't remember tbh, but yeah it was probably a compiler. And true I could execute the program, so any ideas how I could figure out where the code is?

Comment: Have you googled it? There seem to be a number of resources, e.g. [this](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/reverse-engineer-an-old-dos-qbasic-executable).

Comment: I tried dozens of google results, mostly outdated and links to downloads are broken.

Comment: QBasic is an interpreter. QuickBasic is a compiler. If the program has an exe it must have been written in QuickBasic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no public decompiler for QBasic. You can debug or disassemble it, or try contacting [this person](http://02c1289.netsolhost.com/index.htm).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334184/reverse-engineering-a-quickbasic-3-0-program) and [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/reverse-engineer-an-old-dos-qbasic-executable).

Comment: No. We not will pay at least £120 for that.